# How to load .sql file with manage.py

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, manage.py

I have a .sql file from one of my production servers, and am now trying to load it into the database of another. I tried python manage.py loaddata, but its giving me an error

```
CommandError: Problem installing fixture 'social': sql is not a known serialization format.
```

How can I load my data into postgres from a .sql file with manage.py ?

Comment: you don't. you use psql for that

Comment: How do I add an already existing database to psql, it seem like theres no parameter flags for CREATE DATABASE that specify things like host, username, pw, port etc.

Comment: Post a different question please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737752/how-do-you-add-a-pre-existing-database-to-psql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django managment doesn't work with SQL as per documentation on [initial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/)

> A fixture is a collection of data that Django knows how to import into
>   a database. The most straightforward way of creating a fixture if
>   you’ve already got some data is to use the `manage.py dumpdata` command
>
> Fixtures can be written as **JSON, XML** or **YAML** (with PyYAML installed) documents.
>
> Loading data is easy: just call `manage.py loaddata <fixturename>`,
>   where  is the name of the fixture file you’ve created

If you still want to load data with SQL you could make [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-migrations)

Answer (score 21):

You can try

```
cat filename.sql | python manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: I don't know why this get more upvotes. This does answer the og posters question. I understand you want to use `psql` when possible to import a `.sql` file. But I recently had a situation where this was more work than doing it like @leon-chew described. `psql` was not on the same server. I either had to install it, or `rsync` the file to the database, then use `psql` to import it. Or just use this method.

Comment: easy and smooth answer... Thanks

Comment: Perfect! This works as expected!

Comment: This works like magic! I wonder why this is not the accepted answer? On windows, linux cat equivalent to read file content and concat would be type. So on windows use type filename.sql | python manage.py dbshell. You need sqlite3 executable to open an sqlite3 shell and you need mysqlclient for mysql users. Thanks so much @Leon Chew

Answer (score 0):

You can't import straight sql data dump using django. You should use pg's internal db import tools for that.