# How do you add a pre-existing database to Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres in my production server that houses my Django application. I am trying to create a database in psql that already exists. I have the host name, username, password, port, all that good stuff, but after reading Postgres' documentation it seems that there is no way to add in a prexisting database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot create a database if it's already created.

It seems like you have a dump (a .sql file) that you want to load in your production server.

By default `pg_dump` will **not** include the `CREATE DATABASE` statement into the .sql file so you should be able to load the .sql file just doing:

```
psql -h <DB_HOST> -U <DB_USER> -p <DB_PORT> -W <DB_NAME> < <PATH_TO_YOUR_SQL_FILE>
```

Example:

```
psql -h localhost -U db_user -p 5432 -W db_name < /tmp/my_dump.sql
```

That's it.

Let me know if you have any issues doing that.

Cheers

Comment: Ahhh Thank You Abel, you're a life saver. I've been moving our clients servers to AWS, and my brain is just fried now xD. Really appreciate it.